# Is it possible to retrieve final value fee for each eBay category?

Tags: ebay-api

I have noted that it is possible to get a list of eBay trading categories via API.

In addition to that, is it possible to retrieve the final value selling fee for each category along with the exceptions for specific sub categories etc.

---

Clarification: At the most basic level I asked if something is possible, to me that would mean there are really only two answers i.e. Yes and No. If the answer is yes then perhaps the answerer could supply the API endpoint which allows this, which also probably only exists once not "multiple" times.

Comment: Hi Conor. It is true that some broad questions are upvoted and/or answered, and it therefore feels unfair when our own similar questions are downvoted/closed. There has been some discussion on _Meta_ about this, and the community's view is that question that have resisted downvoting/closure cannot be used as evidence of injustice, otherwise arguably nothing would be allowed to be downvoted or closed.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation for [maintaining eBay Categories](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/guides/ebayfeatures/Development/Categories-DataMaintenance.html)

> Initially, use **[GetCategoryMappings](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/GetCategoryMappings.html)** with a DetailLevel value of ReturnAll and no CategoryVersion to get all category mappings. Save the category mapping data locally, including the version value that is returned. This step should be performed at the same time you execute GetCategories so that the metadata returned from these calls is consistent.

Unfortunately, the only documentation I could find on fees is [Fees Resulting from Listing an Item](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/guides/ebayfeatures/Development/Listing-Fees.html). But, eBay fees though are flat with a few exceptions. The list of these exception are:

[Motors vehicles](http://pages.ebay.com/help/sell/motorfees.html), [Real Estate](http://pages.ebay.com/help/sell/realestatefees.html), [Select Business & Industrial categories](http://pages.ebay.com/help/sell/industrialfees.html), [Stores subscribers](http://pages.ebay.com/help/sell/storefees.html), [Classified Ads](http://pages.ebay.com/help/sell/adformatfees.html)

.